# SSO login in desktop application and its inner web-view

Tags: qt, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, identityserver4

There is a web-site/web-api behind a central authentication server ([IdentityServer4](https://identityserver.io/)) and a desktop application (written with [QT](https://www.qt.io/)) which contains a web-view (Qt WebEngine).

The server supports both *OpenId* and *OAuth2*.

The desktop application communicates with some APIs which needs authentication/authorization and the in-side web-view goes to some pages of the web-site which also needs authentication/authorization.

Now, what's the best/secure way to authenticate both desktop application and its inner browser with getting user/password in one action?
The user who login into the desktop should be able to view his/her account and profile in the inner browser, too.

We are looking for a non-hackiee solution. Any option?

Comment: I don't think there is a beautiful solution to that. You can either login in the webbrowser, and extract the token by injecting a script, or login in code (using the QNetworkAuth module) and create a cookie from that token to insert it into the browser - or however the web app needs the token.